# Want to import data from Sheet3 of all workbooks to master workbook?

Tags: vba, excel

The code is working fine but copying data from the active sheet not Sheet3 of workbooks kindly if any one guide me i replaced active sheet with sheet3 but that doesn't work either.

```
Sub copyDataFromMultipleWorkbooksIntoMaster()

Dim FolderPath As String, Filepath As String, Filename As String

FolderPath = "D:\Copy Multiple Excel to One master\"

Filepath = FolderPath & "*.xls*"

Filename = Dir(Filepath)

Dim LastRow As Long, lastcolumn As Long

Do While Filename <> ""
Workbooks.Open (FolderPath & Filename)

LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lastcolumn = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Range(Cells(5, 1), Cells(LastRow, lastcolumn)).Copy
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.Close

erow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
lastcolumn = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(erow, 1), Cells(erow, 1))

Filename = Dir

Loop
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub

Public Function ModDate()
ModDate = Format(FileDateTime(ThisWorkbook.FullName), "m/d/yy h:n ampm")
End Function
```

Comment: a has 2 different "names"... one shown in Excel -> `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3")...`... and a "pointer" (sheetlist in vba) -> ThisWorkbook.Sheet3...

Comment: you copy data from `ActiveSheet` to `ActiveSheet` (in different workbooks)... however you need to change the line `Range(Cells(5, 1), Cells(LastRow, lastcolumn)).Copy` start here with `Sheet3.` cuz without the sheet-pointer it will always select active sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub copyDataFromMultipleWorkbooksIntoMaster()

    Dim FolderPath As String, Filepath As String, Filename As String
    FolderPath = "D:\Copy Multiple Excel to One master\"
    Filepath = FolderPath & "*.xls*"

    Dim lastRow As Long, lastCol As Long, eRow As Long
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Filename = Dir(Filepath)
    Do While Filename <> ""
        eRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & Filename)
        On Error Goto NextFile 
        Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet3")
        With ws
            lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            lastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            .Range(.Cells(5, 1), .Cells(lastRow, lastCol)).Copy
            Sheet1.Cells(eRow, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End With
NextFile:
        On Error Goto 0
        wb.Close False
        Filename = Dir
    Loop
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: subscript out of range appears after doing this ?

Comment: @MFaizanFarooq are you sure that your code *worked* with the ActiveSheet, and that each workbook *does* have a worksheet called "Sheet3"? Also, can you try to locate where in the code the error occurs?

Comment: yes now i added sheet3 to every workbook but now automation error occurs and highlighed this line                                                      lastcolumn = ws.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Comment: umm.. Well I suspect it is in the line that follows. Well, give me a few minutes I will try to edit the whole thing.

Comment: thanks alot it working fine but it is copying the source formatting as well?

Comment: Yes that's an easy stuff simply change to `Sheet1.Cells(eRow, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`

Comment: 1 more option i want that if sheet3 is not present in any of workbook then it should ignore workbook rather than showing subscript error, thanks again for ur time

Comment: yes working fine but at the end subscript error appear after all data is copied to master file